# as3: date.getMinutes > how to add zeros ? (05:09 AM = 5:9 AM)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, date, timer, adobe

How to fix date to retrieve minutes/hours with zeros ?

e.g. it's 05:09 AM >

```
trace(_date.getHours()+":"+_date.getMinutes());  //5:9
```

but i want **05:09** instead of 5:9 - so how to add zeros ??

```
    var _date = new Date();

    ...

    _min = _date.getMinutes();

    //fix date:
                var _str:String = _min.toFixed(1);
                _min = Number(_str);

    trace(_date.getHours()+":"+_date.getMinutes());
```

= 5:9 ....  -_-

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can format it with something like:

minutes_txt:String = _date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + _date.getMinutes() : _date.getMinutes();

which will pad a zero if the minutes is less than 10, and then just trace that instead of only _date.getMinutes

Comment: mhmm I thought, there could be a more simple way, but it's ok. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would write a more generic routine. I've done it two ways:

More traditional approach:

```
    // Pass in 'value' you want to pad, and 'len' as total length of string 
    // to be returned to you. For example, value=24, len=6 would return 000024.
    public static function padIntWithLeadingZeros2(value:int, len:uint):String
    {
        var paddedValue:String  = value.toString();

        if (paddedValue.length < len)
        {
            for (var i:int = 0, numOfZeros:int = (len - paddedValue.length); i < numOfZeros; i++)
            {
                paddedValue = "0" + paddedValue;
            }
        }

        return paddedValue;
    }
```

My own style of doing it:

```
    // Pass in 'value' you want to pad, and 'len' as total length of string 
    // to be returned to you. For example, value=24, len=6 would return 000024.
    public static function padIntWithLeadingZeros(value:int, len:uint):String
    {
        var paddedValue:String  = value.toString();

        if (paddedValue.length < len)
        {
            var leadingZeros:String = "0000000000";
            paddedValue = leadingZeros.substring(0, (len - paddedValue.length)) + paddedValue;
        }

        return paddedValue;
    }
```

Turns out that one is as efficient as the other in terms of lapsed time to execute the function. So, it's just a matter of preference.

R. Grimes